# Concatenation of shell variables

Tags: shell, variables

I'm trying to concatenate, in text, my variables in my shell script but it does not work. I would like to understand why it does not work

```
firstName="Charles"
secondName="Montesquieu"
name="Hello $firstName"
echo "Hello $firstName with $lastName"
output: with Montesquieu
```

I wish I had:
`Hello Charles with Montesquieu`

Comment: The script that you show will __not__ produce the output that you show.  Please correct the question.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/  may be of help. Paste your code and check the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the command, the variable `$lastName` does not refer anything, it is NULL, your correct one is `$secondName`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared $lastName, you wanted to say $secondName no ?

Comment: This is an error when publishing sorry

Comment: It doesn't work even with $secondName ?

Answer (score 0):

In 'echo' instruction you're using

```
$lastname
```

instead of

```
$secondName
```

Try with:

```
echo "Hello $firstName with $secondName"
```

Comment: It's the same thing :/

Comment: It should work, honestly. You're doing it  in console or in a script?